# How to change the numeration of captions

Tags: numbering, captions

My problem is that every time I write `\caption` in a figure, the preceding number increases its value in one unit. Nevertheless, I'd like to group them as in sections. For example, instead of `1,2,3,etc.` I'd like `1.1,1.2,2.1,etc`. The class of document I'm using is an article.

Thank you for your responses.

Comment: I don't mind about tables or equations, I just want to change the numeration in figures. On the other hand, the class is an article, I'll edit my question and add this information.

Comment: Try this `\usepackage{amsmath}` and `\numberwithin{figure}{section}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `\numberwithin` macro from `amsmath` package

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\numberwithin{figure}{section}

\usepackage{lipsum,mwe} 

\title{My nice article}
\author{me}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\section{my first section}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \includegraphics{example-image-a}
    \caption{image-a}
    \label{fig:my_labela}
\end{figure}
\lipsum[2]
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \includegraphics{example-image-b}
    \caption{image-b}
    \label{fig:my_labelb}
\end{figure}

\section{my second section}
\lipsum[3]
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \includegraphics{example-image-c}
    \caption{image-c}
    \label{fig:my_labelc}
\end{figure}
\lipsum[4]
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \includegraphics{example-image-a}
    \caption{image-d}
    \label{fig:my_labeld}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Previously the answer would be to use the `changecntr` package but that facility is now part of basic LaTeX; however `texdoc changecntr` presents the original package manual (at least on my installation).

In your preamble put

```
\counterwithin{figure}{section} % for figures to be numbered within sections
% \counterwithin{table}{section} % for tables to be numbered within sections
```